# Trying to use 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.1' but getting error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i have opened a project already created. I am adding firebase and onesignal. Already added firebase but when i try to add this line getting error:
  `implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.1'`
**Error is: `AAPT2 error: check logs for details`** 
[image]
[image]
*images may not be displayed*, sorry about that.

**build.gradle (module:app) :**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dedeler.com.deredere"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : '82f1gtd7-uy16-4c37-80s4-b1ebd8ad38a6',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: '837758431119'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle (project) :**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When i delete `implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.1'` this line project normally running, I am not getting an error. What should i do? need help..

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `plugin` for that inside *build.gradle* like below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.11.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And inside app level *build.gradle* add this.

**Apply plugin at top**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

**Inside Dependencies.**

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'
```

Comment: When i add classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]' this line, taking this error: Could not find any matches for gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99] as no versions of gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin are available.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray. ...

Comment: @Berkan I have updated answer. Please Check updated answer and follow and apply that changes.I have tested and *gradle* builds successfully. And make sure you added all details correctly as my answer and didn't miss anything.

Comment: thanks, but now i have different issue, if you can help, I would be grateful. When run the project, i can't see user on onesignal.com . What should i do for this?

Comment: @Berkan I didn't get you exactly what you are saying. Please explain bit more.

Comment: I created a project. This project is connected with Firebase and Onesignal. I can send notification to my application through both Firebase and Onesignal. But they gave me a project that was already created. I put Firebase and Onesignal stuff into this project. I can send notifications via Firebase, but Onesignal can not find my application. I will show you both gradles

Answer (score 1):

This build.gradle from doesn't work on Onesignal (and no error)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dedeler.com.dedede"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : '18u4a466-37t1-4f9n-bacd-cac2ed8f9c3c',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: '357658431414'
        ]


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This build.gradle from normally working on Onesignal:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.berkancalikoglu.onesignalpushdemotutorial"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : '9a39e119-d312-4517-a145-ea00482fa037',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: '260945562180'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Why does Onesignal work one and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

Include this code in your App/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'
```

> i have solved by adding this classpath dependency and later change it

Answer (score 0):

1. Just Go to Your build.gradle (android/app).
2. And remove the `

   apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
3. And re-run project and error will be resolved.`